# How to change locale settings on Fedora Docker container?

Tags: docker, fedora

On a normal server e.g. a Linode VPS I would normally do:

```
localectl set-locale LANG=<locale>.utf8
timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>
```

But since systemd is not present or does not work on containers I get:

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

Now, my goal is just to change these settings **without using systemd** but such approach seems to go undocumented. Is there a reference for non-systemd alternatives to config tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some documentation about locale setting in arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale

In Dockerfile, adjust `LANG` to your desired locale. You can add more than one locale in `/etc/locale.gen` to have a choice later.

Works on debian, arch, but `locale-gen` misses on fedora:

```
ENV LANG=en_US.utf8
RUN echo "$LANG UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
RUN update-locale --reset LANG=$LANG
```

More general is `localedef`, works on fedora, too:

```
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
localedef --verbose --force -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `Dockerfile`

```
ENV TZ=America/Denver
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit .bash_profile or .bashrc from root and add the following.

```
TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
export TZ
```

Save file and commit image after its done.

Comment: There is no need to that as you can set `ENV=Asia/Kolkata` in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score -1):

Based on a technique used in sti-base, I came up with the following workaround for https://github.com/ncoghlan/fedbuildenv/blob/09a18d91e7af64a45394669bac2595a4b628960d/Dockerfile#L26:

```
# Set a useful default locale
RUN echo "export LANG=en_US.utf-8" > /opt/export_LANG.sh
ENV BASH_ENV=/opt/export_LANG.sh \
    ENV=/opt/export_LANG.sh \
    PROMPT_COMMAND="source /opt/export_LANG.sh"
```

`BASH_ENV` covers non-interactive `bash` sessions, `ENV` covers `sh` sessions, and `PROMPT_COMMAND` covers interactive `bash` sessions.

this seems to be the debians's equivalent of locale-gen:

```
RUN localedef -v -c -i fr_FR -f UTF-8 fr_FR.UTF-8 || true
```